# Facebook login replace email sign up and log in

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I haven't look into using facebook to login stuff.. Before I begin my project, I would like to know whether should I develop the system using email sign up and log in first? or it's needless because I may redo everything when I chose to add login via facebook later?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you know for certain that you are going to get users without Facebook, you can leave the normal email sign-up. 
Once a user has logged into your app using Facebook you can access most of the details you would normally ask during normal signup (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/). But you'll need to take in to consideration that while for the time-being Facebook has many users, in the future it may not always be like this, and you'll need to have a back-up sign-up system in place if you expect your app to be used for a long time. 
It is not too difficult to add the Facebook login on top of already existing login functionality and you can use the data you gain from the Facebook login to still implement your normal login.

Comment: thanks for the advise! I thought of that matter too, I think it would be easier to integrate if I done my logic with manual login :)